# db2 recent sql update statements

Tags: db2

We have recently had an issue in our production environment where it looks like someone has updated a table and we want to identify recently run `UPDATE` queries.

Is there a system view on db2 that I can query that shows recently run sql where I can do a wild card search. Something like `LIKE '%UPDATE%'`?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer assumes that you're running DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows.

Generally, unless you have an audit policy defined and active in your database, you won't be able to get this information.

You may have an option to look at the archived transaction logs (assuming your database is enabled for roll forward recovery).  IBM sells a product called Recovery Expert that can go through the transaction logs, or you might be able to write a program that calls either the `db2ReadLog()` or `db2ReadLogNoConn()` APIs to try and find the spurious update statement.